# Is there going to be a new contest soon?

Tags: discussion, contest

I noticed that the last PoTW contest ran about a month ago. On that post it states the likely next theme but when is that contest going to run?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm sorry for dropping the ball for the past several weeks. I am back now, and will be reviving the PotW contest shortly.

Comment: No worries! It's not super important haha. But I'm happy to hear that it will be coming back!

Comment: I was thinking about asking a meta question about the voting, not that it matters of course. I get the feeling that earliest posts may tend to score highly and the late posts will not get noticed, because of the nature of how things work. Has there been any discussion about this? Yes it doesn't seem to matter much, and there doesn't seem to be any way for all the posts to be made but unviewable, then suddenly all revealed for viewing at the same time. Analysis for a recent contest: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJHJ0.png

Comment: @uhoh Yeah, there's definitely a benefit to early-posting, when it comes to upvotes, for _any_ answer to questions in Stack Exchange. That's definitely one of the drawbacks about the idea of "evergreen" questions on SE.

Comment: @scottbb have any workarounds been contemplated, like for example a 7 day informal moratorium on voting then some kind of mod generated "announcement" that voting is now open, so please go take a look at the candidates? It would be analogous to announcements of voting for moderators but lower key. Naively it sounds like a good idea but I don't know if it's practical.

Comment: @uhoh There's really no way of having an open question to collect submissions, without votes, and then let people have a voting period. Not using the standard question/answer format of SE. Some people have suggested using SE's moderator election. system for such voting contests. But it's not available for us to use within the site at all. Moderator elections are run by the SE admins. That functionality hasn't trickled down for site voting/polling purposes, unfortunately.

Comment: @scottbb okay got it. Code Golf SE is essentially one giant contest, but "winning" there is not based on votes but instead the shortest code/script for a given language. If there were several SE communities that did already have long-running contests that could benefit from a new feature, I suppose a new feature request inquiry could be posted in the main meta to test the water. Those usually get quickly shot down but occasionally one gets added to a "someday" list, and less occasionally one even eventually gets implemented several years down the road.

Comment: In the mean time there's no real damage to time-skewed voting here; after all they're only *metapoints* :-)

Comment: Please define *shortly* :)