# What happened to the Photo Competition?

Tags: discussion

For quite some time, there has been a [Photo Competition](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo-competition), but it seems to have ended as of 6 June, 2022.

What happened?

Was there lack of interest/entries? Was it a late victim of the Covid Craziness?

I always enjoyed looking at other's work, and I miss it.

Comment: For avoidance of doubt: the closing of this as a duplicate is very definitely "without prejudice", just that the answer I've posted there still applies. tl;dr: it's a surprising amount of work and it can't be delegated.

Comment: No worries and thanks for the link, @PhilipKendall. That didn't come up in the "related questions" list at all. Sorry about increasing the mod workload, even though it was slight...

Comment: No need to apologise, it's a fair question - we're honestly on top of the "regular" mod workload, just don't have the time for "extras" like the photo competition.

Comment: Also related: [Is there going to be a new contest soon?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7257/15871)